# GridLayout ngfor row column

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm new with Nativescript and I've a problem with ngFor. I've this GridLayout with inside a StackLayout with ngFor, the question how to set dynamic col and row inside the StackLayout?
Thans.

```
<GridLayout columns="*,*,*" rows="{{ totalRows }}" class="grid-book">
   <StackLayout *ngFor="let plan of plans; let i = index" row="0" col="0" horizontalAlignment="stretch">
      <StackLayout height="150" class="book">
         <AbsoluteLayout height="150">
            <StackLayout width="100%" left="0" top="0" height="100%" class="orange internal-book"></StackLayout>
            <Label text="" left="70" top="0" width="5" height="100%" backgroundColor="white"></Label>
         </AbsoluteLayout>
      </StackLayout>
      <Label text="{{ plan.name }}"></Label>
   </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `index` as you are assiging it to `i` in this case.
I have tested below case in my html.

```
<GridLayout columns="*,*,*"  class="grid-book">
  <StackLayout *ngFor="let plan of plans; let i = index" row="{{i}}" col="0" horizontalAlignment="stretch">
    <StackLayout height="150" class="book">
      <AbsoluteLayout height="150">
        <StackLayout width="100%" left="0" top="0" height="100%" class="orange internal-book"></StackLayout>
        <Label text="" left="70" top="0" width="5" height="100%" backgroundColor="white"></Label>
      </AbsoluteLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label text="{{ plan.name }}"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

and in my .ts file  `plans = [{ 'name': 'Name 1' }, { 'name': 'Name 2' }, { 'name': 'Name 3' }];`

and if you see output using debugger
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but I’ve a big json not only 3 elementare, for example I ve 25 objects and are divided into a grid of 3 columns a N rows. Thanks

Comment: row="{{i}}" is dynamic and it can be N number of rows.

Comment: @Narendra it shows each book on new row. what about a grid? for example 2 x N grid?

Comment: @RobertWilliams you can make columns dynamic as well. row="{{i}}" col="{{i%/2 ===0 ? '0' ? '1'} }"

Comment: @Narendra keeping row = i won't assign new row to each child? if so then it will not result in 2 x n grid

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have just added to show that how to use dynamic columns. You can also try `wraplayout`

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed number of columns (3) and an unbounded number of rows (totalRows). Instead of populating one large GridLayout I'd suggest making a StackLayout with an ngFor your outermost Layout, and put the GridLayout with 1 row and 3 columns inside that loop template.

Something like this:

```html
<StackLayout *ngFor="let plan of plans">
    <GridLayout rows="*" columns="* * *">
        <Label text="A" col="0"></Label>
        <Label text="B" col="1"></Label>
        <Label text="C" col="2"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Once you have the basic loop and layout working then you can substitute the Labels with your custom, per-cell template. If you use this Grid-inside-Stack technique you do not need the i/index or the totalRows string value.

Comment: An alternative form for this:

`

<StackLayout>
    <ng-template ngFor let-plan [ngForOf]="plans">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="* * *">

`

Answer (score 0):

You may use property binding on rows / columns to keep it dynamic. But you will easily hit performance issues if you have so many divisions in a GridLayout (like 20 or 25+).

In my opinion you should use StackLayout to stack items next to each other in vertical orientation and use a GridLayout inside each item to divide the columns. Also I would recommend using a ListView instead of ngFor if possible.